# How to write velocity operator of a given Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, lattice-model

Let us have a 2D lattice model with three sites in one unit-cell (basically 2D Kagome lattice). In Fourier space, the Hamiltonian is written as

$$
H = \sum_{k_x,k_y}
\begin{bmatrix}
a^\dagger & b^\dagger & c^\dagger
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11}&h_{12}&h_{13}\\
h_{21}&h_{22}&h_{23}\\
h_{31}&h_{32}&h_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}\equiv\Psi^\dagger h({k_x,k_y}) \Psi
$$
here $a,b,c$ are operators of particles on 3 sites of the unit-cell.

**Question:**

How to write the velocity operator for $a,b,c$ particles in x-direction and y-direction separately.

**My attempt:**

Using Ehrenfest theorem for particles $a$, we have:

$$\partial_t a^\dagger a = \frac{1}{i\hbar}[a^\dagger a,H]$$

(to not make it a shopping-question:)
I think the Ehrenfest theorem is the right way to write velocity operators. But I don't see how exactly one can separate velocity of particles in x- and y-directions or $k_x,k_y$ directions using this theorem. How does quantum mechanics define velocity in different directions?

Comment: Have you tried considering the commutator of H and X/Y?

Comment: @JahanClaes yes, but how do I define X and Y operators here? (pardon me if this is a very stupid question)

Comment: Your question title needs to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 2):

In the first quantization representation the velocity operator is obtained using
$$\hat{\dot{x}} = \frac{1}{i\hbar}\left[\hat{x},\hat{H}\right]_-,$$
which defines *the operator of the derivative* or *the derivative of the operator*, depending on whether you work in Schrödinger or Heisenberg picture.

In second quantization one switches to the operators using the usual prescription  - calculating the matrix element between the field operators $\psi^\dagger(x),\psi(x)$.

For trancated Hamiltonians, like it seems to be the case in the question, one is usually interested in the *current operator*, which is obtained using the continuity equation, as the derivative of the charge operator in the region of interest, e.g.
$$\partial_t a^\dagger a = \frac{1}{i\hbar}\left[a^\dagger a,\hat{H}\right]_-.$$
A caveat is that one may have some challenges when switching the gauge, e.g., when trying to apply the Kubo formula (doable, but not straightforward).